# Infer tuple type from tuple union type based on one element

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type that is a union of tuples:

```js
type TupleUnion = ["a", string] | ["b", number] | [Foo, Bar] // ...
```

I want to define a function that takes a parameter of any type `K extends TupleUnion[0]`, and I want the return type to be inferred as the second element of the same tuple:

```js
function f<K extends TupleUnion[0]>(key: K): ValueFor<K>
```

How can I define `ValueFor<K extends TupleUnion[0]>` to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) utility type to filter a specific union member from `TupleUnion` where the member is a tuple with a first element `K`. Afterwards we can return the second element of the extracted tuple.

```
declare function f<
  K extends TupleUnion[0]
>(key: K): Extract<TupleUnion, [K, any]>[1]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=86&pln=8&pc=1#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAMQPZLgXjgbzgQwFxwDOYATgJYB2A5nAL6iSxwBCOJ6WcARgcedXVBDw0eABUArlAA2MAKoUySChwDaAIhzqANEVKUqAXTgAfOBq464FCQFsuMEsbOrkSXayfCAJjADG0mzwAGYSFH5gSirBADwA0nAwAB5gMBTehHCSMvKKyqoADIYAfAAUANYwEARxAJQEAKIpJDgRMdmyClG6qnG6OBQQJaoAjIbCoH7KxHAkIxzBpZrqtaAA9GtwW3AAegD8QA)

---

Edit:

To address the issue in the comments.

```
type ValueFor<T, K> = T extends [any, any] 
  ? K extends T[0] 
    ? T[1]
    : never
  : never

declare function f<K extends TupleUnion[0]>(key: K): ValueFor<TupleUnion, K>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=78&pln=8&pc=1#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAMQPZLgXjgbzgQwFxwDOYATgJYB2A5nAL6iSxwBCOJ6WcARgcedXVBDw0eABUArlAA2MAKoUySChwDaARgA0RUpSoBdOAB84qvnu0UJAWy4wShk6uRJtrB8MbwAajmkSYZBIAHjFtAGkAPg4xOBgADzAYCgATQlMcCghtTIhDUDg4AH44cLjE5LS4MVUABnyQQsKSmvV9AqaCChgAN3sOrt7%20kFAUmABjaTZ4ADMJCnGwJRUZ4LKEpNT0yRl5RWU6-UiACgBrGAgCcIBKAl9-QKQQndkFZYjIgG5hUHHlYjgJHUHBmxwARDgwddQAB6GFNOAAPSKQA)

Comment: This almost works. If I have TupleUnion = [1, number] | [string, string], f(1) is correctly typed to number, but f('a') is incorrectly typed to never (expected string). I assume this is because no member of the union is assignable to ['a', any]. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: I was able to solve this by defining another utility to find all first-elements that K can be assigned to, and substituting that for K.

Comment: type AssignableKeys<T,K> = T extends any ? K extends T ? T : never : never;