# How to implement generic but interlinked tuples in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

My request handler function can receive some specific types of requests. The type of the response is fixed for each request type. For example, the `[requestType, responseType]` tuple would be like this:

```js
type OneChoice =  ['123', string] | ['456', boolean];
```

So, for a `request === '123'`, the only valid response type is a `string`.

**Update**: note the response is not returned from the function, but instead, it is passed to another function as an argument.

I am not able to implement this in Typescript. I tried the obvious:

```
function handler1<T extends OneChoice>(request: T[0], sendResponse: (arg: T[1]) => void): null {
  if (request === '123') {
     sendResponse(false);
  }
  return null;
}
```

But the above code compiles, whereas, it should not. Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do? I read the docs but did not find anything related.

**Update**: I tried the answer suggested in comments, and it did not work:

```js
type OneChoiceMap = { [T in OneChoice as T[0]]: T[1] };

function handler2<K extends keyof OneChoiceMap>(request: K, sendResponse: (arg: OneChoiceMap[K]) => void): void {
  if (request === '123') {
    sendResponse('alpha'); // error, not expected!
  }
}

handler2('123', false); // error, expected
handler2('123', (arg: string) => {}); // works, expected

function handler3<K extends OneChoice[0]>(request: K, sendResponse: (arg: Extract<OneChoice, [K, any]>[1]) => void): void {
  if (request === '123') {
    sendResponse(false); // works, not expected!!
  }
}

handler3('123', false); // error, expected
handler3('123', (arg: string) => {}); // works, expected
```

[**TypeScript playground with links to all examples**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdhAwgCwPYEsDG0C8UDaA5AIwBMAzIQDRQDOwATunAOYC6UAPgYQCwCsANmpQARqlQAbCAEM4bANwAoUJFgIUGbAFkZYKHgDeBACpRm6pGizQZtKCfwAGNmwBcD-MQ4BfZUoAzAFc4TGB0VDgoZDkAE2kGYgAeMwgAD2AIOFj7eCstCAA%20AAoGCABHIIh6D0cXGlos2IAlarBIxo9imQYWWq82AEoDQqgANwxYwY84IMlJKEMlKHMAqFKKqvoDHDwSCkJhpZWVxuzW2na4RuLCGUkwGMOFKAB6V6gAd1QGAGtaGjpSBhCCxZYnM4tNodCDFAL3RqDF7vL4-f40OCoYBQIEQEGxACEBPBpyaFyuN1m8yRbw%20EAYDB%20gLSwMyYJWPnBZWAQQYUSpkmUnMCITCESiMWyCVISQA0jiMk17L8ICBUGs8pobLowCUypVqsAPLKGmTodcIF0en1LFqdHp8LKhiNxpNpq70LFFuD0GsNgbtrs9mRKEcSXQzZcYbd7o8ZM9aTiGUyoJjsbj8UTw5DydH4ZJEci6cmGBisQrWaCsycI%20dzZS5pIaSj6YzSxW8WzwZzhZL4vTSLcQyJ84XE62Uxmu33pUODjRur0PPQmKxhjhRoYfM2Pt8-gCO-ilCLQuFItE4glyHKFZlsrkNNZsM42HrNobjaa61GLVal1AAFEMgYGQwiSTUnwgGhHRoOQQFfAZ11GCZPXdFCvWOVZ1n1LZsSDKB9lDb0axzetYTuB4nh3VF92ZSt2QhSMKVhUcIGovd0VTcspyrYkSKY6MBXYtEDzTQ82WrKAe2PGd6XIOdKBoVjqIndseLBWSGHkwiREXG0V2YFgkMWbcixozj1KAA)

Comment: Replace `false` with `9` and look at the error.   Type '9' is not assignable to type 'T[1]'.
  Type '9' is not assignable to type 'string | boolean'.  That may help you understand what it is happening...

Comment: @JayBuckman I understood that. I want to make sure that the return type is tied to the parameter value. If the parameter value is `'123'`, the only allowed return type should be `string`. I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: It's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73057476/infer-tuple-type-from-tuple-union-type-based-on-one-element

Comment: My suggestion would be to refactor to something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZ1j4N) where the compiler can see what you're doing as a generic indexing operation.  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi @DawidRusnak, thanks to your comment. Actually in an attempt to simplify the question I ended up changing its meaning. My query is different. I have updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Hi @jcalz , thanks to your comment. Actually in an attempt to simplify the question I ended up changing its meaning. My query is different. I have updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: So does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBJRDN) meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer, if not, what am I missing now?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. It's very close! Actually, my real use case is still slightly different. The `request` is an object and not a string. I have appended my update to the [ts playground](https://tsplay.dev/WP1pew). I hope it's not confusing, and thanks for the help! If you can solve it, please post it as an answer directly.

Comment: I'm getting a bit tired of having the question change in response to my suggestions; your latest version isn't working because of a missing feature, requested at [ms/TS#18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758), and working around that usually involves a custom type guard function.  But at this point I am worried that if I make a suggestion (like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbEQ8N)) the scope of the question will drift further.  How should I proceed here?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. sorry about the constant drifting! I was not aware of all the complexities in TypeScript, and I was trying to simplify my question to make it easy for people to answer. I will not make any more updates. Please feel free to post your final version as an answer to this question. Really thanks for your help!